# Request to IP camera Javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to make a request into an IP camera, but the camera needs Basic authentication, i need to get this request and show in an Iframe or img, but i don't know how to get that, i see how the request to the camera stays always waiting to finish an send some data, but i don't know how to get it and pass to the Iframe, thank's for any help.

Code Example:

```
function makeRequest(method, url, data) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.open(method, url);
      xhr.setRequestHeader(
        "Authorization",
        "Basic " + btoa("user:password")
      );
      xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
          resolve(xhr.response);
        } else {
          reject({
            status: this.status,
            statusText: xhr.statusText,
          });
        }
      };
      xhr.onerror = function () {
        reject({
          status: this.status,
          statusText: xhr.statusText,
        });
      };
      if (method == "POST" && data) {
        xhr.send(data);
      } else {
        xhr.send();
      }
    });
  }

  //GET example
  makeRequest("GET", "http://ip_camera_url").then(
    function (data) {
      var results = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(results);//Never come here
    }
  );
```

**UPDATE:**

First the request return status 200

[image: request 1]

then keeps sending data

[image: request 3]

[image: request 2]

but the request never ends and i can't get the result or the images the ip camera returns.

[image: request 4]

this is the message in the tab timing into the network option.

Comment: Could you edit your code to tell us what you get when the code runs, anything in the console, network tab of the devtools, etc.

Comment: Are you saying that onload never gets called?